# How would I extract numbers from column names based on a match condition in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe like this,

```
  val df = Seq((12,14,56,22,18),(11,54,83,91,12)).toDF("individual_rule_1_professional",
"individual_rule_2_amateur","team_rule_3_professional","team_rule_4_amateur","total")
```

and I would like to extract the rule numbers of columns that start with individual and end with amateur into an array. So in this case it would return [2], because there's only one column in the dataframe that starts with individual and ends with amateur, and the rule number for that column is 2.

How would I do this?

Thanks so much! Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the column names using `df.columns`

```scala
df.columns
// Array[String] = Array(individual_rule_1_professional, individual_rule_2_amateur, team_rule_3_professional, team_rule_4_amateur, total)
```

And then apply basic pattern matching on it to extract the rule number (which I have assumed to always be a digit)

```scala
df.columns.filter(_.matches("individual_.*_amateur")).map(_.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""))
// Array[String] = Array(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
df.columns.filter(c => c.startsWith("individual") && c.endsWith("amateur"))
  .flatMap(_.split('_').flatMap(_.toIntOption))
  //or if the number you want is always in the second position
  //.flatMap(_.split('_')(2).toIntOption)
//res1: Array[Int] = Array(2)
```

the differences with @phlantorvert's answer:

- outputs an `Array[Int]` instead of `Array[String]`
- Avoids any issue if the word "individual" is not instantly followed by a `_` character (but still assumes the separator is `_` character). This conforms better to your specification that the column name should: "...*start with"* and *"...end with"*